# Missing constructor for initialization for map

Tags: c++, xml, c++11, xml-parsing

I had some help on a previous topic, where I had to change my map to use int in combination with strings. When I have done this it gives me a different issue. This is the issue:

```
src/main.cpp:11:29: error: no matching constructor for initialization of
      'std::map<int, std::string>'
  ...tagMap {{"1", "data"}, {"2", "entry"}, {"3", "id"}, {"4", "content"}};
     ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It seems like the issue (which I looked up on another topic) seems to allude to the fact that the issue is to do with making your constructor take const references? I don't really understand how to implement this.

```
#include "pugi/pugixml.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    pugi::xml_document doca, docb;
    std::map<std::string, pugi::xml_node> mapa, mapb;
    std::map<int, std::string> tagMap {{"1", "data"}, {"2", "entry"}, {"3", "id"}, {"4", "content"}};

    if (!doca.load_file("a.xml") || !docb.load_file("b.xml")) {
        std::cout << "Can't find input files";
        return 1;
    }

    for (auto& node: doca.child(tagMap[1]).children(tagMap[2])) {
        const char* id = node.child_value(tagMap[3]);
        mapa[id] = node;
    }

    for (auto& node: docb.child(tagMap[1]).children(tagMap[2])) {
        const char* idcs = node.child_value(tagMap[3]);
        if (!mapa.erase(idcs)) {
            mapb[idcs] = node;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why "1", "2", etc.? Your map says `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try sth like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   std::map<int, std::string> tagMap {make_pair(1, "data"), make_pair(2, "entry")};
}
```

**Edit:** The version without make_pair function is also valid:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   std::map<int, std::string> tagMap {{1, "data"}, {2, "entry"}};
}
```

The only thing you need to remember is that you shouldn't rely on compiler const string literal to number cast...

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Although this get's me closer is still gives me the error: ```src/main.cpp:20:30: error: no viable conversion from 'mapped_type' (aka
      'std::__1::basic_string<char>') to 'const char_t *' (aka 'const char *')
        for (auto& node: doca.child(tagMap[1]).children(tagMap[2])) {
                                    ^~~~~~~~~```

Comment: in line 20 try: `auto id` instead of `const char* id` similarly in line 25.

Comment: That seems to give me the same error ```src/main.cpp:20:30: error: no viable conversion from 'mapped_type' (aka 'std::__1::basic_string<char>') to
      'const char_t *' (aka 'const char *')
        for (auto& node: doca.child(tagMap[1]).children(tagMap[2])) {```. Is this a related error or should I open a new question

Comment: @JamesWillson, I suspect those `child` and `children` functions take `const char *`. You're in luck because [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) has a function to get a `const char *`.

Comment: @chris Thank you for the reply. But I don't understand how to use std::string in this case :S

Comment: chris meant you could give it a try in yourstring.c_str()

Comment: @chris Like this? ```const std::string& idcs = node.child_value(tagMap["3"]);```?

Comment: @JamesWillson, Just like any other class. Barring reading an article or section of a book on how to use it, you can search for APIs that meet your needs and then use those APIs. In the case of `std::string`, you're lucky because there is plenty of reading material and more than one set of documentation, compared to some libraries that have neither.

Comment: I suppose rather: `auto idcs = node.child_value(tagMap[3].c_str());`